# Explain " :> " command

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have found this command few years ago and used it since then to empty file.

But how this really works?

**`:>`**

used like

**`:> /server/logs/access_log`**

Comment: Seems a little unnecessary to use the ":" command for this.  Why not just "> filename" ?

Comment: looks like you're right, no need to use `:` operator. Never tried that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`>` is the redirection operator. `:` is a builtin shell command, and is equivalent to to the `true` command, it is used mostly as a placeholder in scripts.

`:> filename` will make your file empty.

Answer (score 7):

In bash, `help :` gives you:

```
:: :
    No effect; the command does nothing.  A zero exit code is returned.
```

It worth noting that,as it was mentioned before, `:` usually takes the place of true, like in

```
while :
do
   date
   sleep 60
done
```

But strictly speaking, `:` it's not needed in your command and you can simply write

```
> /server/logs/access_log
```

To avoid truncating important files inadvertently it's better to set noclobber option

```
set -o noclobber
```

and if you try to do it, it will spit

```
-bash: /server/logs/access_log: cannot overwrite existing file
```

if you want to force it

```
>| /server/logs/access_log
```

Answer (score 3):

Being `:` the "do-nothing" operator in bash (equivalent to `true` as WebMonster points out), this command actually creates and truncates to size 0 the following file.

Note that usually to create an empty file that does not exist, one can use `touch`, but if the file exists and has data, you have then to empty it. This is a way of doing both things at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a shell on a unixoide operating system. Normally the ">" command sends the output of a command to a file.

I'm not quite sure what ":" does, but it seems that this part is the "nothing" that is sent to your file.